# Вывод с базы данных в handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, аутентификация, handlebars

пытаюсь сделать сайт с регистрацией и авторизацией, но еще не дойдя до самого сложного столкнулся с проблемой - при попытке сделать вывод данных пользователя происходит ошибка:

Access has been denied to resolve the property "mail" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.

Не могу понять как исправить, вот форма регистрации:

```
<form class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" action="/reg" method="post">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Your e-mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="mail">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="name">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{button}}</button>
</form>
```

Роутер:

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const User = require('../models/user');
const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('reg', {
        title: 'Register',
        button: 'Register',
        name: 'Your name'
    })
})

router.get('/log', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('log',{
        title: 'Login',
        button:'Log-in'

    })
})

router.get('/users', async (req, res)=>{
    const user = await User.find({})

    res.render('users',{
        title:'Users',
        isUser: false,
        user
    })
})

router.post('/reg', async (req,res)=>{
    const person = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        password: req.body.password,
        mail: req.body.mail
    })
    await person.save()
})

module.exports = router
```

Модель пользователя:

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema({
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mail: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = model('user', schema)
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const userRoutes = require('./routs/users')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()
const hbs = expressHandlebars.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs'
})

app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views','views')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use(userRoutes)

async function start(){
    try{
        await mongoose.connect('link',{
            useNewUrlParser:true,
            useFindAndModify:false
        })
        app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
            console.log("server has been started")
        })
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

И я ведь вижу что в базе есть пользователь, но не могу понять как с ним работать
насколько я знаю обращаться к его значениям нужно по ключу, но у меня почему-то не выходит